# DRBD StandAlone with new resource

Tags: drbd

I have two nodes "A" (primary) & "B". Each node have 3 resources. On node "B" i replace disks and after that i add each resource as secondary. Two resources successfully connect and sync, but with one resource i have issue. When on node "B" i stop this resource, node "A" shows

```
lv1 role:Primary
  disk:UpToDate
  b.host connection:Connecting
```

When i starts this resource on node "B", node "A" shows:

```
lv1 role:Primary
  disk:UpToDate
  b.host connection:StandAlone
```

and node "B" shows:

```
lv1 role:Secondary
  disk:Inconsistent
  a.host connection:Connecting
```

I try everything, remove/add resource, metadata on node "B", remove data, rebuild raid `drbdadm connect lv1 --discard-my-data` etc.
One difference between worked an broken resources is `This node was a crashed primary, and has not seen its peer since`

```
       +--<  Current data generation UUID  >-
       |               +--<  Bitmap's base data generation UUID  >-
       |               |                 +--<  younger history UUID  >-
       |               |                 |         +-<  older history  >-
       V               V                 V         V
E43824C7BC375B4A:626476078D91E933:CC1DC3FAD143EDCC:E4E71860FBA887C2:1:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
                                                                    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
                                      -<  Data consistency flag  >--+ | | | | | | | | | | |
                             -<  Data was/is currently up-to-date  >--+ | | | | | | | | | |
                                  -<  Node was/is currently primary  >--+ | | | | | | | | |
 -<  This node was a crashed primary, and has not seen its peer since  >--+ | | | | | | | |
             -<  The activity-log was applied, the disk can be attached  >--+ | | | | | | |
        -<  The activity-log was disabled, peer is completely out of sync  >--+ | | | | | |
                              -<  This node was primary when it lost quorum  >--+ | | | | |
                                          -<  Node was/is currently connected  >--+ | | | |
                              -<  The peer's disk was out-dated or inconsistent  >--+ | | |
                                 -<   A fence policy other the dont-care was used  >--+ | |
                  -<  Node was in the progress of marking all blocks as out of sync  >--+ |
                     -<  At least once we saw this node with a backing device attached >--+
```

Any ideas how i can fix it?

**UPD:** Find new differences `a kernel: drbd lv1/0 drbd1 b.host: The peer's disk size is too small! (999671944 < 1000196216 sectors)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case on node "A" (primary) i have LVM, on node "B" i have MDRAID. This differences give me difference in resource size in 524 272 sectors. What i do to save my data. I run both resources in primary mode, mount and copy data from "A" to "B", then i rebuild node "A" to MDRAID and sync resources.